# I want to modify the values ​in the table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I want to make changes through the event so that the user can directly modify the values ​​in the table.
The current data is linked with MongoDB.
However, if an onchange event occurs in the current TextField, its value will not change normally.
How should we solve it?

I tried to bind the event by declaring it as a function, not as a variable, but it was useless.

```
const handleChange = (e, name, i) => {
  const { value } = e.target;
  this.setState(state => ({
    data: state.data.map(
        (row, j) => (j === i ? { ...row, [name]: value } : row)
    )
  }));
};

const row = (
  x,
  i,
  header,
  startEditing,
  editIdx,
  handleChange,
  handleRemove,
  stopEditing
) => {
  let currentlyEditing = editIdx === i;
  return (
    <TableRow key={`tr-${i}`} selectable= 'false'>
      {header.map((y, k) => (
        <CustomTableCell key={`trc-${k}`}>
          {currentlyEditing ?
            <TextField
              name={y.prop}
              onChange={e => handleChange(e, y.prop, i)}
              value={x[y.prop]}
            />
           :
            x[y.prop]
          }
        </CustomTableCell>
      ))}
      <CustomTableCell>
        {currentlyEditing ? (
          <CheckIcon onClick={() => stopEditing()} />
        ) : (
          <EditIcon onClick={() => startEditing(i)} />
        )}
      </CustomTableCell>
      <CustomTableCell>
        <TrashIcon onClick={() => handleRemove(x)}/>
      </CustomTableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
};
```

I think the code now seems to change the value of the array.
However, data is passed from MongoDB to the object.
So what if need to change the value of a field in that row in an object?

Comment: What is "this" in your `handleChange` function? Because this looks like completely detached code, in which case `this.setState` will do nothing, so you probably want to look at your dev console for errors.

Comment: This is all my code. Thank you for your help.
https://gist.github.com/itlockit2/614f13d65d981192555e32cb77b7bc9b

Comment: Please remember to read and follow the advice in ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask): if you have code, reduce it to a [mcve] and then put that code in your question. Don't add links to off-site files, because those links can expire making your questioning meaningless for future visitors of the site (which is a large part of SO: you're not just asking your question for yourself, you're also asking it for everyone else who might run into the same problem in the future). And note that making that MCVE is as much for your benefit as ours: you may find the problem all on your own.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to shorten it, but I thought you wanted the whole code. What should I do?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the general approach. Usually you take a copy of your code and you start removing everything that isn't _directly_ related to your problem. Text? turn it into a single word placeholder. CSS? Unless the problem _is_ the CSS, it's irrelevant and you can remove it entirely. A table with a header, multiple rows, and dynamically generated cells? Remove the header and generate only _one_ cell. Or hardcode that structure, even better. etc.